# Cart List with Customer ID Magento API

Tags: soap-api-v2

I would like to get Cart List with specific customer ID.
**I get cart info with cart id but i can't find with customer ID.**

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html), the `shoppingCartInfoEntity` content contains a `customer_id` entry as well as the other extra customer related data:

- customer_tax_class_id
- customer_group_id
- customer_email
- customer_prefix
- customer_firstname
- customer_middlename
- customer_lastname
- customer_suffix
- customer_note
- customer_note_notify
- customer_is_guest

If you don't get any customer related information, maybe it is because the cart has been abandonned by a non logged in customer.